# json array not deserialized correctly

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a problem with ASP.NET MVC 4 when posting json data to an mvc action.

I used a `Dictionary<string, string[]>` to represent a javascript object containing multiple named arrays. But instead of storing the array values in one key, each array value got its own key

```
var data = { 
    foo1: { bar1: ['a', 'b', 'c' ], bar2: ['z'] },
    foo2: { bar3: ['d', 'e' ] } 
};
$.ajax({
    url: '/mvc/SomeAction',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: myCallback
});
```

My MVC model looks like this:

```
public class Data 
{
    public Dictionary<string, string[]> foo1 { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string[]> foo2 { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SomeAction(Data data) 
{
    // Instead of having a key named bar1 with the value as an array of strings, 
    // this is what I get:
    // data.foo1 = 
    // { 
    //     (key: "bar1[0]", value: null), 
    //     (key: "bar1[1]", value: null), 
    //     (key: "bar1[2]", value: null),
    //     (key: "bar2[0]", value: null)
    // }
    // etc..
}
```

It seems like the MVC model binder does not correctly deserialize the json to the data model.

This only occurs if the value of the dictionary is an array, if it is another object it works as expected.

Any ideas on how to solve this are very much appreciated.

In the worst case I'll have to use `JSON.stringify` and parse the string on the server, but that does not feel right.

Comment: That's what supposed to happen. An array of data incoming should be translated to indexed elements. Any kind of `IEnumerable` will end up in `var[N]` where `var` is the identifier name and `N` is an index.

Comment: @BradChristie Could you explain why it is supposed to be like that? I would expect the key to be `"bar1"` and the value to be `["a", "b", "c"]`.

Comment: What I'm elluding to is that the protocol expects that if a single variable name has multiple values instead of `foo=1,2,3` the request is instead `foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3`. Now, as far as why MVC isn't translating correctly, I'm not sure. But what you have shown is how it should be sent over the wire.

Comment: I can see that this would be the case if the data is passed in the query string or as form values, but as it is passed as json, I would think that would'nt be a problem.

Comment: Except that jQuery is going to conform to that spec (any JSON passed in through an AJAX call is passed to [`jQuery.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) which converts it to the [format I was referring to](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/serialize.js#L36-67).)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this plugin for jQuery](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com.ar/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html) to convert json data:

```
var data = $.toDictionary({ 
    foo1: { bar1: ['a', 'b', 'c' ], bar2: ['z'] },
    foo2: { bar3: ['d', 'e' ] } 
});
```